# Highlight table row when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when a row is clicked, it gets highlighted (to make it clear that it is the currently selected row). And when another row is clicked, the previously selected row becomes un-highlighted and the new one becomes highlighted.

As of now, what happens is that when I hover over a row, it gets highlighted (which works as planned), but when I click the background-color of the rows do not change. Some of my code is below, thanks in advance.

Here is some example **HTML**:

```
    <tr class="text_data selected_grey" onclick="getReportDetails(this, 'johndoe@gmail.com');">
        <td class="text">John</td> 
        <td class="text"> Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text_data selected_grey" onclick="getReportDetails(this, 'sarah@gmail.com);">
        <td class="text">Sarah</td> 
        <td class="text">Dean</td>
    </tr>
```

This is the relevant part of my **Javascript** getReportDetails function.

```
function getReportDetails(elem, email) {


var j_elem = $(elem);

$(".text_data").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(j_elem)) {
        j_elem.addClass("selected_grey");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("selected_grey");
    }
});
```

And this is the involved **CSS**.

```
.text_data {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: none;
}
.text_data:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
.selected_grey {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

EDIT: It turned out to just be a cache problem.

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/4q4ym4xf/

Comment: whoa, that is weird..still not working on my app. Might actually have something to do with the rest of the css? I will investigate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To toggle the table row click, check like below:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ta6r6e7g/

HTML:

```
<table>
      <tr class="text_data selected_grey" onclick="getReportDetails(this, 'johndoe@gmail.com');">
        <td class="text">John</td> 
        <td class="text"> Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text_data selected_grey" onclick="getReportDetails(this, 'sarah@gmail.com);">
        <td class="text">Sarah</td> 
        <td class="text">Dean</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".text_data td").on("click", function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent();
    if(tr.hasClass("selected")) {
        tr.removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        tr.addClass("selected");
    }

});
```

CSS:

```
tr.selected td {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.table_row').click(function() { //Once any element with class "table_row" is clicked
    $('.table_row').removeClass('selected'); // "Unselect" all the rows
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // Select the one clicked
}
```